# Retrieve result for all the users

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have one query which returns particular user total hours for a month. I want to return for all the users in an org.

UserRegistration table contains UserID.

My code for particular user is,

```
 SELECT isnull(SUM(isnull([1],0))+SUM(isnull([2],0))+SUM(isnull([3],0))+
               SUM(isnull([4],0))+SUM(isnull([5],0))+SUM(isnull([6],0))+SUM(isnull([7],0))
              +SUM(isnull([8],0))+SUM(isnull([9],0))+SUM(isnull([10],0))+SUM(isnull([11],0))+
               SUM(isnull([12],0))+SUM(isnull([13],0))+SUM(isnull([14],0))+SUM(isnull([15],0))+
               SUM(isnull([16],0))+SUM(isnull([17],0))+SUM(isnull([18],0))+SUM(isnull([19],0))+
        SUM(isnull([20],0))+SUM(isnull([21],0))+SUM(isnull([22],0))+SUM(isnull([23],0))+
        SUM(isnull([24],0))+SUM(isnull([25],0))+SUM(isnull([26],0))+SUM(isnull([27],0))+
        SUM(isnull([28],0))+SUM(isnull([29],0))+SUM(isnull([30],0))+SUM(isnull([31],0)), 0)
     FROM dbo.timesheet where month ='August' and [year] =2015 and [Task ID] in(select
 TaskID from ManageTasks where TeamMemberUserID = 136)
```

Comment: Removing the WHERE clause doesn't give you what you need?

Comment: Do you mean you want the grand total (one result for all the users) or a (separate) total for each user?

Comment: @James no, then it would just be a single sum for all team members; presumably, they want a row per team member, showing each team member's hours.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to use [`GROUP BY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx):

```
SELECT mt.TeamMemberUserID ---, <all those crazy SUM expressions>
FROM dbo.timesheet AS t
INNER JOIN dbo.Managetasks AS mt
ON t.[Task ID] = mt.TaskID
-- ... <WHERE clause> ...
GROUP BY mt.TeamMemberUserID;
```

If you need the user's names, there are several ways to do this, here's one:

```
SELECT u.UserName --, <all those crazy SUM expressions>
FROM dbo.timesheet AS t
INNER JOIN dbo.Managetasks AS mt
ON t.[Task ID] = mt.TaskID
INNER JOIN dbo.UserRegistration AS u
ON mt.TeamMemberUserID = u.UserID
-- ... <WHERE clause> ...
GROUP BY u.UserName;
```

Since apparently you want a row for every user, even those that don't have any logged hours for tasks in the selected month(s), try:

```
SELECT u.UserName --, <all those crazy SUM expressions>
FROM dbo.UserRegistration AS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Managetasks AS mt
ON mt.TeamMemberUserID = u.UserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.timesheet AS t
ON t.[Task ID] = mt.TaskID
-- ... <WHERE clause> ...
GROUP BY u.UserName;
```

I do recommend more consistency in column names. Why is it `Task ID` in one table and `TaskID` in another? Why is `UserID` expanded to `TeamMemberUserID` in one table? Is it possible to have a `TeamMemberUserID` who is not a `UserID`, or vice versa? Consistency is important - I should be able to identify an entity by its column name regardless of what table it exists in.

Comment: TeamMemberUserID is not from dbo.timesheet table. TeamMemberUserID from Managetasks table.

Comment: @user74234 Ok, concept is still the same